# Multiline Label Merging with lower DIV

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, label

I'm using two DIV s one below the other. In the Top DIV I'm using a Multiline Label in which data is generated Dynamically.

When the Data in the Label is a bit larger then Space is not generated but the exceeded data merges with the lower DIV

Here is the Css for Div

```
white-space:inherit;
```

Here is the Css for Label

```
float: left;
width: 30%;    
overflow:auto;
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Seems like a CSS issue. Share your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the fist DIV class name `.container` and write css as -

```
.container{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The `label` is merging into `next div` because it has `float: left` property. `overflow: hidden;` will help you prevent this behavior.